# Is there a Manufacturer ID list for windows phone ?

Tags: 8.0, 7.5

I'm looking for a list that match manufacturer id (RM-846_eu_euro1_267) to commercial names (Nokia Lumia 620).

Is this list exist somewhere ?

Thank you !

Comment: [Something like this](https://github.com/ailon/PhoneNameResolver/blob/master/PhoneNameResolver.cs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a nicely formatted list available, but an app developer has written some code which lists all known Windows Phones (so far).

Even if you're not a programmer, you should be able to get the info you need from this file...

https://github.com/ailon/PhoneNameResolver/blob/master/PhoneNameResolver.cs

Comment: Hey guys. I can't leave a question so inclined to Dev here on WPSO. Can you both help me to make it more "consumer aligned"? Sometimes AdDuplex show info like that and maybe it can a consumer doubt.

Comment: @VitorCanova move to Stackoverflow?

Comment: I'm afraid they will reject the the way it is.